# Jenkins docker not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, deployment, jenkins-plugins

**My jenkins is having problem:**

- docker compose up -d
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/starter Nuxt3@tmp/durable-42b6a537/script.sh: 1: docker: not found

I am having a Ubuntu cloud server. I can manually run docker compose up -d in the server, but it is not working in with Jenkins script.

**This is my Jenkins:**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node'
            args '-u root'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Link Files') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Link the files, assuming they are in the same directory
                    sh 'ln -sf docker-compose-local.yml docker-compose.yml'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Install Dependencies') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'npm install'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'npm run build'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'docker compose up -d'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```